# Can I force a BTRFS volume to reside on a specific disk

Tags: btrfs

I have a btrfs filesystem mount as / (root) and /home. I have two drives in my filesystem,

```
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 233.79GiB
    devid    1 size 922.51GiB used 115.00GiB path /dev/sda3
    devid    2 size 931.51GiB used 123.03GiB path /dev/sdb1
```

/dev/sdb1 is an SSD and /dev/sda3 is a normal HDD.

To my untrained eye, it looks like both these volumes are spread across both disks

```
$ sudo btrfs device usage /home
/dev/sda3, ID: 1
   Device size:           922.51GiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,single:           108.00GiB
   Metadata,single:         7.00GiB
   Unallocated:           807.51GiB

/dev/sdb1, ID: 2
   Device size:           931.51GiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,single:           121.00GiB
   Metadata,single:         2.00GiB
   System,single:          32.00MiB
   Unallocated:           808.48GiB

$ sudo btrfs device usage /
/dev/sda3, ID: 1
   Device size:           922.51GiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,single:           108.00GiB
   Metadata,single:         7.00GiB
   Unallocated:           807.51GiB

/dev/sdb1, ID: 2
   Device size:           931.51GiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,single:           121.00GiB
   Metadata,single:         2.00GiB
   System,single:          32.00MiB
   Unallocated:           808.48GiB
```

I can't seem to find a command that will definitively show how the two directories (subvolumes?) are spread across the drives.

So my question. Is there a way to force /home to reside on one disk and / to reside on the other.

Thx.

Comment: "Is there a way…?" – Yes. Two separate BTRFS filesystems, each on its own device.

Comment: To guide you we need the output of the following commands: `btrfs fi df /`, `df / /home`, `lsblk`, `grep -E 'btrfs|/boot' /etc/fstab`, `mount | grep -E 'btrfs|/boot'`. Are there other subvolumes in the BTRFS filesystem? Which device holds the primary bootloader? Any quirks you are aware of? (like [mounting via systemd, beyond `fstab`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90785/108618) etc.)

Comment: Can you not add and remove respective devices to each subvolume? The data should be moved to the correct place. I would recommend backing up the lot before trying anything.